# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profiles/user-follow-feed/ User has no user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Well i am just trying to show feed back of the following users but got an error:**RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profiles/user-follow-feed/
User has no user.** I don't understand how can i fix it. Need help to fix it out. many thanks in advance.

views.py

```
class FolloweHomeView(View):
   
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    

        user = request.user.userprofile
        is_following_user_ids = [x.user.id for x in user.follower.all()]
        qs = Post.objects.filter(username__id__in=is_following_user_ids).order_by("-create_date")[:3]
        return render(request, "profiles/follower_home_feed.html", {'object_list': qs})
```

models.py

```
class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def toggle_follow(self, request_user, username_to_toggle):
        profile_ = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username__iexact=username_to_toggle)
        user = request_user
        is_following = False
        if user in profile_.follower.all():
            profile_.follower.remove(user)
        else:
            profile_.follower.add(user)
            is_following = True
        return profile_, is_following

        
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name ='is_following',blank=True,)
    avatar = models.ImageField(("Avatar"), upload_to='displays', default = '1.jpg',height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None,blank = True)
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
   
    objects = ProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/user-follow-feed/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'accounts',
 'posts',
 'profiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\grapPub\grabpublic\profiles\views.py", line 99, in get
    is_following_user_ids = [x.user.id for x in user.follower.all()]
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\grapPub\grabpublic\profiles\views.py", line 99, in <listcomp>
    is_following_user_ids = [x.user.id for x in user.follower.all()]
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 420, in __get__
    raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(

Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profiles/user-follow-feed/
Exception Value: User has no user.
```

if more detail is require than tell me i will update my question with that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `follower` is a `ManyToManyField` to the `User` model, so the `x` in the list comprehension is a `User` object:

```
is_following_user_ids = [x.id for x in user.follower.all()]
```

You however do not need to perform this kind of logic, you can directly filter with:

```
qs = Post.objects.filter(
    username__user__is_following__user=request.user
).order_by('-create_date')[:3]
```

this will query the `Post` objects in a single query.

---

> **Note**: A `ForeignKey` does *not* store the string representation (or name) of the
> referenced object in the column, it stores the primary key of the record it
> references in a column with an  `_id` suffix to a `ForeignKey` field. Therefore
> `ForeignKey`s usually do *not* end with a `name` suffix. You might want to
> consider renaming the <s>`username`</s> field to `author`.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

Comment: Now it showing me :**FieldError at /profiles/user-follow-feed/

Related Field got invalid lookup: is_following**

Comment: @FlashMaddy: but the `related_name='is_following'`? And `username` is a `ForeignKey` from `Post` to `User` or to `UserProfile`?

Comment: @FlashMaddy: this is also relevant if you filter with `username__id__in=`, in fact it is even more risky, since if you mix primary keys of `User`s and `UserProfile`s, it can result in a `QuerySet` with the *wrong* data.

Comment: `username = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` this is field from post model

Comment: @FlashMaddy: then it is `username__user__is_following__user`. Your original filtering would not only result in an *N+1 problem*, but also show invalid data.

Comment: Now it showing me : **ValueError at /profiles/user-follow-feed/

Cannot query "testuser": Must be "User" instance.**

Comment: @FlashMaddy: but you need to use with `request.user`, not the `user` object. So the item at the right of `=` should be a `User` object...

Comment: Is there any other way to do it in a robust way?

Comment: @FlashMaddy: yes, I would strongly advice to re-model this. Cleaning up the current assymetrical modeling of a follower relation. Also fix the nomencalture: right now the nomenclature is the opposite, since basically you use `follower` as `following` and vice-versa. :)

Comment: If you dont mind can you update my model and post it as a answer ?